# Monoidal functors and their projection functors

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories

I first posted this post as a math
I as I am instructions proceed.

Suppose $M$ and $N$ are monoidal categories and let $M\times N$ denote the associated product category. $M\times N$ comes equipped with two natural projection Functors $\pi_M:M\times N\to M$ and $\pi_N:M\times N\to N$. I am interested in the pushout of the diagram of $\pi_M$ along $\pi_N$. A pushout of the aforementioned diagram is a monoidal category $P$ along with two monoidal Functors $\phi_M:M\to P$ and $\phi_N:N\to P$ such that the diagram commutes. I'm familiar with push-outs in set theory but I'm not sure how to go about finding the push out of one monoidal functor along another. Any elucidation of $M$

Comment: Your last sentence is incomplete (and the first one doesn't make sense). Could you edit your post to fix them?

Comment: Perhaps the first sentence is an autocorrect-induced mangling of "I first posted this [on math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4175976) but got no answer."

Comment: Be careful before you ever claim to be familiar with pushouts  in a particular category. I think your construction trivialises.

Comment: There is nothing special about the product here, better forget about it. Let $F : K \to M$, $G : K \to N$ be two monoidal functors. You want to find the pushout $M \sqcup_K N$. (It seems that you want to have everything strict here?) How would you solve this problem for one-object monoidal categories aka monoids? Once you have done that, try to generalize it. There *are* free monoidal categories etc.